H2O GradientBoostingEstimator (GBM) - Group subitems of a feature together for training
I have the scenario where you have a feature, call it X, with possible values it can hold, say x1, x2, x3, x4. I want the GBM in H2O to train x1 and x3 together so that they are predicted with the same output value.
Any suggestions how to do this would be appreciated. :)

What is the use case for this scenario? Is it the classification or regression problem? It always depends on the training data. From training data, the model learns how to predict. If you have the same output value for X1 and X3, the model will also expect the same predicted value for these features for test data.
I don't know any reason to constrain model output for concrete values. If you want the output to be the same for x1 and x3, you can pick the predicted value for x1 and replace it with the predicted value for x3.

It is for regression. The problem with your solution, is you are loosing all the data for x3 in the training stage, and so the model will not perform as well as it could have.
Instead, I am looking for a way to group x1 and x3 together so that it trains them as the same, even thought their values aren't.

Hi Adam. I still don't understand your problem well. Could you please explain your issue using a simple example with concrete data? Thanks!
